# Confusion in the definition of Threshold Frequency

Tags: terminology, frequency, photoelectric-effect

I had some confusion regarding the definition of "Threshold Frequency"
Threshold Frequency:  It is defined as the minimum frequency of incident light which can cause ejection of electrons from the metal surface "WITHOUT ANY KINETIC ENERGY".
I didn't get the phrase above in BOLD.I mean no kinetic,no velocity,are the electrons levitating or what???

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we graph the maximum kinetic energy of the photoelectrons as a function of frequency. We get a graph that looks like this:

[image: Energy vs frequency]

([from the Hyperphysics page on PE](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod2.html))

This is the actual data from Millikan's 1916 experiment. If we extrapolate to zero kinetic energy we find  corresponding minimum frequency below which no photoelectrons are ejected i.e. we say that at this frequency the KE of the ejected photoelectrons falls to zero.

That doesn't mean that if we shone light with a frequency of (in this case) $4.39 \times 10^{14}$ Hz we'd get photoelectrons with zero kinetic energy. In practice nothing would happen. The phrase is a shorthand way of saying the kinetic energy goes to zero as the frequency approaches the cutoff frequency.

The cutoff is of course because the photoelectrons need a minimum energy of $\phi$ to escape the metal, where $\phi$ is the work function, and the cutoff frequency is given by $hf = \phi$. To escape the metal **and be detectable** we need some slightly greater energy $hf+\epsilon$, where the magnitude of $\epsilon$ will depend on the experimental conditions.

Answer (score 0):

As with lots of things there is a threshold which is a mathematical nicety.

A frequency slightly less than the threshold results in no photoelectrons.

A frequency slightly more than the threshold results in photoelectrons with a little kinetic energy.

You can then make the "slightly" as small as you like.

Rather then go through all this rigmarole the statement is made that at the threshold frequency the photoelectrons have zero kinetic energy and from that you can infer what happens if the frequency is above or below the threshold frequency.